# Remove all extensions in zsh

Tags: zsh

Say I have a directory with many files with the .bak extension, and want to remove this from each. What's the simplest way to do that? I mean a command that would do what one might exspect from `mv *.bak *`.

Comment: Beware, `mv *.bak *` does not achieve what you want at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### With `zmv`

Zsh has `zmv`, which offers a very simple interface to renaming (or copying) files:

```
autoload zmv
zmv '(*).bak' '$1'
```

Every pair of parentheses captures a group, which can then be accessed with `$1`, `$2`, and so on. Here are [some more examples](http://zshwiki.org/home/builtin/functions/zmv).

Another way to do it with `zmv` is to use the `-W` option, which works for simple rename tasks:

```
zmv -W '*.bak' '*'
```

The easiest way to have `zmv` always available is to put the `autoload zmv` statement in your `~/.zshrc`.

---

#### With Bash-syntax

If you want to use "plain" Bash syntax with string manipulation, this would do it:

```
for f in *.bak; do mv -- "$f" "${f%.bak}"; done
```

---

#### With the `rename` tool

There's a `rename` tool that is available on some Linuxes and on OS X through [`brew install rename`](http://brew.sh/).

```
rename 's/.bak$//' *
```

The `$` is necessary to capture the end of the string, and not parts in the middle of the file names that happen to contain `.bak`.

Comment: on `zsh 5.8 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)` `rename` is not available.

Comment: @Timo `rename` has nothing to do with Zsh. It's a Perl utility script available through package managers.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the fine answers given, there’s also the *very* old-fashioned way that should work on any POSIX-compliant system — even one without a modern shell like bash or zsh:

```
for f in *.bak; do mv $f `echo $f | sed -e 's/\.bak$//'`; done
```